# Java, strong typing, covariance and contra-variance

Tags: java, covariance, contravariance, structural-typing

While studying for a test in my OOP course, I came upon this question which had an answer I didn't really understand. The question is as follows (translated):

The programming language "Sava" is similar to Java in every way except in the following:

1. It's structurally typed
2. When overriding a method the argument can be contravariant and the return type can be covariant.

Given the following class and interface, is the following assignment legal?

```
  interface I{
    boolean equals(I i){…}
  } 

  class C{
    boolean equals(C c){…}
  }

I i = new C();
```

The answer that was given to this question was:
The assignment isn't legal. The equals method in C changes the paramater in a covariant way and so it doesn't match the equals method in I.

At first I thought the professor forgot to add "Implements I" but the answer also stated the following:
Answers that refereed to the fact that C doesn't implement I weren't accepted because given that it's a Structurally Typed language it doesn't matter if it were a subtype.

I'm not sure I understand how we can refer to these methods as covariant / contravariant if there is no relation of subtyping between C and I.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: I think that the professor forgot to add an `implements I` after `class C`...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a made-up language; probably better-suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com.


Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - I updated the post to answer your comment. In short, he didn't forget to add the `imlements I`.